# New Users Tend to Post Questions With Titles Containing Most Words Starting With a Capital Letter

Tags: discussion, feature-request, title

I've been editing out tags from question titles for the past several hours, and I noticed that a lot of questions have that pattern, especially from new users. I don't know who and when decided that it's the way to go, but that is clearly:

1. Less readable;
2. Obstructs readers' ability to quickly identify key words.

There should be automatic detection of that silly nonsense and notification, maybe even automatic decapitalizing if every or most (~>70%) words in the question title begins with a capital letter.

Comment: Of the edits I've done, these are the most painful/tedious to deal with.

Comment: It's actually pretty common in English that the title of an article, question, whatever be cased like that when it doesn't form a complete sentence.

Comment: @animuson I get that, but this isn't the place to go by that rule. And if that's the case, user should be notified that question titles should be phrased like complete sentences.

Comment: I See Your Point About Not Using A Title Casing In Question Titles; But People Have Been Forced To Do So Since Their Schooling. Old Habits Die Hard.

Comment: @hjpotter92 I've been used to being a huge duck around people, but then experience taught me it's actually by far better to be nice to people, that way they are nicer to you in response. Also the question title is a nice illustration of the problem and is likely to get people think "Oh, *that* title problem!" and act on it with more enthusiasm.

Comment: How was @hjpotter not nice to you...? I don't see why you would say that...

Comment: Uhh... That was just an example of an obvious thing to learn and be happy to use afterwards, because ultimately it's better in a lot of ways. Not implying somebody wasn't nice to me in this post. It's all cool. Being cool is also great. Learn and chill, guys :)